# Batch to remove first line, Add filename to each line and merge TXT files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, prompt

I've got a bunch of TXT files (nearly two hundred) to which I need to perform the following tasks:

1. Remove the first line of text from each file;
2. Add the filename(without extension) to the beginning to each remaining lines in the files;
3. Merge all into one single TXT file.

I know that the following command will do the merging:

> for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f">> output.txt

and this one adds a predefined text to the beginning of each line in a single txt file:

> (for /f "delims=" %L in (filename.txt) do @echo sometext%L)>>
>   output.txt

Any suggestions on how I could make it work? All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: would be easy without the first condition: `findstr /v "IKnowThisStringDoesntExistInAnyFile" *.txt >single.txt`

Comment: do you want to keep empty lines?

Comment: @Italo Saraiva, just letting you know that pure batch will be very slow at doing this on very large files.  I do this very task to append file names to the end of each line and combine all the files together.  I use a program call SFK (Swiss File Knife) but it will not give you the ability to skip the first line. I usually make a second pass of the data to remove the header records.  For the size of the files I use, it is still 100 times faster then using pure batch.

Comment: @Italo Saraiva, you should probably chose Aacini's answer.  It uses a single FOR command which will be much faster.

Comment: @Squashman, I just noticed something about Aacini's code. If ENTER hasn't been pressed at the end of the last line on the text files the output gets messed up. Any idea why that happens? It's odd because that doesn't happen with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method eliminate the first line, preserve empty lines and insert the file name. I think it also should run faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "file="
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "^" *.txt') do (
   if "%%a" neq "!file!" (
      set "file=%%a"
   ) else (
      echo %%~Na:%%b
   )
)) > output.tmp
REM ren output.tmp output.txt
```

The output file is *not* named with `.txt` extension in order to avoid re-processing of its contents.

Comment: Pure genius. That makes total sense.

Comment: you like to work with flags, don't you? Very elegant.

Comment: Squashman suggested I should pick your method as the right answer. It does work just as his did. Thank you. =)

Comment: by the way...mind explaining how is this possible with a single for? I'm also curious about the ('findstr "^" *.txt') part of the code.

Comment: Although I like that my answer be the selected one **`;)`**, I suggest you to base your selection in a more objective point, like a timing test! This command: `findstr "^" ...` return _all lines_. When the filename part includes a wild-card, findstr insert the filename at beginning of the returned lines separated by colon...

Comment: @Aacini Hi. I just realized something about your code. If there isn't a blank line at the end of the text files (if ENTER hasn't been pressed at the end of the last line of text) the output gets a little messed up. Any idea why that happens? It's odd because that doesn't happen with Squashman's code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this all from the cmd prompt.  Double the percent symbols if you want to run it from a batch file.

```
for %F in (*.txt) do for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %L in ("%~F") do echo %~nF%L>> output.txt
```

Should you need it to keep empty or blank filled lines the second for loop changes to this.

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1* delims=:" %L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%~F"') do echo %~nF%M>> output.txt
```

Comment: replace `sometext` with `%F`. But this doesn't remove the first lines and skips empty lines

Comment: This did the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

this removes empty lines, but also removes first lines and adds the filename to every line:

```
@echo off
>Output.txt (
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%l in ('more +1 %%f') do (
    echo %%f:%%l
  )
))
```

Comment: If there are more than 65,000 lines in the file, more will pause waiting for user input.